# How to get datetime from oracle varchar with surrounding characters

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a varchar2 'Printed 4/21/2014 3:00:00 AM' and want to get just the '4/21/2014 3:00:00 AM' as a date.
My thought was to use something like:

I have: REGEXP_SUBSTR('Printed 4/21/2014 3:00:00 AM', '[0-9/ :APM]*$')
Results in: 4/21/2014 3:00:00 AM

However,

SELECT
  to_date(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Printed 4/21/2014 3:00:00 AM', '[0-9/ :APM]*$'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  FROM DUAL;

results in an 'Invalid Month' error.

Suggestions?

Comment: Well, the problem has two parts. First you need to remove any extra text, which is not part of the string representation of a date (date-time). That is done by the call to `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, and your query does it correctly. But then, in the code you do something you didn't mention in the problem description: you want to further apply `TO_DATE` to the result. The issue in your attempt, obviously, is that the resulting date-time is not in the `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'` format, it is in the `'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'` format.

Comment: Do you know the format of the date (date-time) ahead of time? If not, this last part (which has nothing to do with the first part) will be impossible to solve.

Comment: Ah, I got it.  I really only need the date, and can ignore the time.  In this case: SELECT
  to_date(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Printed 4/21/2014', '[0-9\/]*$'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 1):

Issue:
Correctly identified by mathguy - date format

I decided I don't really need the timestamp, thus:

SELECT
  to_date(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Printed 4/21/2014', '[0-9/]*$'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  FROM DUAL;

works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is fixed - including the text you want to ignore - then you could convert the whole string to a date or timestamp, without needing to use a regular expression or substring:

```
select to_date('Printed 4/21/2014 3:00:00 AM', '"Printed" MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') as result
from dual;

RESULT             
-------------------
2014-04-21 03:00:00
```

The fixed 'Printed' part is treated as [a character literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A) by enclosing that part in double quotes inside the format model.

If you really aren't interested in the time then you can remove that afterwards:

```
select trunc(to_date('Printed 4/21/2014 3:00:00 AM', '"Printed" MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')) as result
from dual;

RESULT             
-------------------
2014-04-21 00:00:00
```